# Iteratively add values to a zeros matrix from another matrix with non-zero values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 100x100 matrix "A" and I want to create a new 100x100 matrix "B" that only contains a set of values of the higher values of "A", and the rest of elements with zeros.

How can I do it iteratively, by adding one entry at a time?

In fact, I want to do the following:

I have a matrix "A" from which I've computed the minimum spanning tree (matrix "B"), but now I want to add the higher values of "A" to this MST matrix at a time until the matrix has a desired density.

So I need to add a value at a time, compute the matrix density, and continue adding values the higher values of matrix "A" until I get a desired density in matrix "B".

Comment: `B = np.where(A>thresh, A, 0)` or `B = A*(A>thresh)`.

Comment: In fact, I want to do the following:

I have a matrix from which I've computed the minimum spanning tree, but now I want to add values to this MST at a time until the matrix has a desired density.

Comment: Have you not described the solution? loop over: (1) Compute density of (B), if satisfied, end. (2) Find the next zero value of B, replace it with its nonzero counterpart of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that density is proportional to the number of elements, you can use [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
A = ... # 100, 100 array
n = ... # number of elements you want
M = np.zeros_like(A)

ind = np.argpartition(A, -n, axis=None)
M.ravel()[ind[-n:]] = A.ravel()[ind[-n:]]
```

Even if your density estimate is not as clear cut as this, this allows you to build an effective binary search or other iterative algorithm to find the right number of elements.